# What does it mean if the rational class is equal to the conjugacy class?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

For a finite group $G$ and $g\in G$, the rational class of $G$ is defined to be the set of all conjugates of $g^i$, where $i$ is coprime to the order $|g|$ of $g$.

If the rational class of $g$ is equal to the conjugacy class of $g$, then this means that $g$ is conjugate to every $g^i$ where $\gcd(i,|g|) = 1$. This seems like a very strong condition. What are the implications of this for the (in terms of the?) representation theory of $G$? (I know very very little about representation theory) How rare is this?

What if we assume that $g = xyx^{-1}y^{-1}$, where $x,y$ generate $G$? How does this affect the answers to the above questions?

I'm particularly interested in the case where $G$ is simple, for example, $A_n$ or $PSL_2(\mathbb{F}_q)$.

Comment: Not clear to me the statement: *What if we assume $g=xyx^{-1}y^{-1}$?*

Answer (score 1):

This condition is equivalent to the condition that the complex irreducible characters of $G$ all have rational (hence integer) values at $g$. Famously, it holds for the symmetric groups $S_n$ for every $g \in S_n$.

To show this, observe that if $g$ is order $n$, $\gcd(i, n) = 1$, and $\chi$ is a character, $\chi(g^i)$ is the result of applying the automorphism of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$ given by $\zeta_n \mapsto \zeta_n^i$ to $\chi(g)$. Hence $g$ is conjugate to $g^i$ iff $\chi(g) = \chi(g^i)$ for all irreducible $\chi$ iff $\chi(g)$ always lies in the fixed field of this automorphism for all irreducible $\chi$.

$g$ being a commutator makes this condition slightly easier to satisfy because you don't have to consider the 1-dimensional characters.

Comment: Do you know if the sizes or orders of the conjugacy classes of a group have any significance in terms of its representations theory?